# Functionality of window when you pass it in javascript file

Tags: javascript

What is the purpose of window in the following?

```
(function (window) {
    //do_something
})(window);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates an anonymous function that accepts a parameter called `window`, and then immediately calls it with the `window` global variable.

This strategy is often used to avoid dirtying up the global namespace.

Comment: If the entire function is a file, how do you pass in `window` to a file?

Comment: This code assumes it is being run from a browser. In that case, `window` will always be defined. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp